# How In-Call status bar impacts UIViewController's view size?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, statusbar, in-call

I'm trying to understand how the `view` associated to a `UITabBarController`, `UINavigationController` or `UIViewController` reacts when the in-call status bar is toggled.
My trouble is that they seem to behave differently and this causes me side effects.

I've made a project that changes the root view controller of the window for the 3 types above and I dump the `description` of the `view` to get the frame coordinates.

---

- `UIViewController`

[image]

inCall status **OFF**:

```
UIView: 0x4e2a1f0; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; ....
```

**ON**

```
UIView: 0x4e2a1f0; frame = (0 40; 320 440); autoresize = W+H; ...
```

This one I understand : when the in-call status bar appears, the height of the view of the UIViewController shrinks and looses 20, and its y coord moves from 20 to 40.

**That's perfect ! I would expect the same when replacing a classic `UIViewController` with a `UITabBarController` or a `UINavigationController` but that's not the case !**

---

- `UINavigationController`

  [image]

InCall status bar **OFF**

```
UILayoutContainerView: 0x4b35ab0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; ..
```

**ON**

```
UILayoutContainerView: 0x4e1b060; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; ..
```

In that case, the view handled by the UINavigationController does not have its frame properties changed when the in-call status bar is toggled?! (why ? :( )

---

- `UITabBarController`

[image]
**OFF**

```
UIView: 0x4b2f6a0; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; ...
```

**ON**

```
UIView: 0x4b2f6a0; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; ...
```

Same as in the `UINavigationController`: the `view` of the `UITabBarController` does not seem to be impacted when the incall status bar is toggled.

---

Can someone explain me how this resize works when displaying the incall status bar appears ?
My end goal is to display a `UIView` that is shown **ABOVE** the whole `UITabBarController` and that resizes properly when the in call status is displayed. However, I really don't know where to put such a view in the views hierarchy : if I add it as a child of the UITabBarController's view, as this one does not react to the incall status display, mine does not react as well :(

Answer (score 17):

The height of the view when the In-call status bar is toggled depends on the way it's anchored.

Play around with the autoResizingMask of the UIView to control whether the view should move down or resize when the in-call status bar shows up.

These two properties,

```
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
```

will help you. The first one pushes the view down, the second one changes the size.

Answer (score 4):

Your regular UIViewController example has [`wantsFullScreenLayout`] set to NO, which causes the view to be automatically sized so it doesn't go under the status bar.

UINavigationController and UITabBarController, on the other hand, default `wantsFullScreenLayout` to YES. So their views take up the whole window, and they size and position their subviews themselves to appropriately handle the status bar. If you explicitly set the property on these controllers to NO, you should get the behavior you desire (but will then lose the ability to properly handle child controllers that set `wantsFullScreenLayout` to YES, if you care about that).

In your UITabBarController example, BTW, it seems that you are not printing the information for the view of the tab bar controller; here that is a UILayoutContainerView, not a plain UIView.

Comment: Hum, quite interesting comment, I'm going to give a try to your hint ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should forget about how much amount the view gets resized and play around with Autoresizing mask.